# Trying to write SQL query where I need to join 5 tables

Tags: sql, join

I am fairly new to SQL. I am working on a query script where I need to join date from five tables. I have no way to test this, so I am not sure if it's right.

```
SELECT  tblQCC.CSN, 
        tblQCC.question_id, 
        tblQCC.answer, 
        tblEncounters.CSN, 
        tblEncounters.department_id, 
        tblEncounters.prc_id, 
        tblEncounters.patient_id, 
        tblEncounters.account_id, 
        tblEncounters.ser_id, 
        tblEncounters.visit_date, 
        tblPatient.patient_id, 
        tblPatient.patient_name_last, 
        tblPatient.patient_name_first, 
        tblPatient.MRN, 
        tblPatient.DOB, 
        tblAccount.account_id, 
        tblAccount.benefit_plan_name, 
        tblSer.ser_id,  
        tblSer.provider_name
FROM    theQCC
JOIN    tblEncounters 
ON      tblQCC.CSN = tblEncouter.CSN
JOIN    tblPatient 
ON      tblEncounters.patient_id = tblPatient.patient_id
JOIN    tblAccount 
ON      tblEncounters.account_id = tblAccount.account_id
JOIN    tblSer 
ON      tblEncounters.ser_id = tblSer.ser_id
WHERE   tblEncounters.depatement_id = 500
AND     tblQCC.answer = ‘yes’
AND     tblEncounters.visit_date <= 2016-12-10;
```

Comment: For one thing, your date `2016-12-10` needs to be quoted. As is, it evaluates to 1994.

Comment: is it related to mysql or sql-server? please tag your question for one dbms.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Can you show us your database hierarchy, I will be able to help you

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. It's a sql-server. I will fix the date tags. napi15 what do you need to see?

Answer (score 0):

First off, what database?

Specify your JOINs.  Are they INNER, OUTER, LEFT, RIGHT?

Do you have tables with acceptable null values coming in?

Quotes around the date part ... etc.

Comment: It's a sql-server. I want to do INNER joins. I believe there are null values coming in. Sorry I don't have a ton of answers. I was asked to write the script, but I can't actually test it.

Comment: @RSmith Verify that in each table there are valid values matching you records for each of your `INNER JOIN`s.  For exampe, if `tblEncounters.depatement_id = 500` valid?

How do you not have test access on a development database?  Even with just READ access?